# How to add a page divider between each page load using Jquery Infinite-scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I want to simply add content between each page load using Jquery Infinite-scroll. So for example, after page one, I'd like to add a mini-footer with some links. You could think of it as a type of page divider.

I've checked out the Infinite-scroll js file but I can't find where I should add a new function to insert the divider.

I'm currently working with Masonry, but this question is specifically about the Infinite-scroll js file. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code or at least what library you're using

Comment: I thought about posting code, but I simply don't know which bit of code to post without posting the whole Jquery Infinite-scroll js file. The file can be found here: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ The only file I'm using from that page is: jquery.infinitescroll.dev.js I was hoping that someone familiar with Infinite-scroll would know where I could add the page divider content.

Answer (score 0):

There is a customization section that could help:

```
Customization
This information will probably help styling.

<div id="infscr-page-2" class="infscr-pages"> will contain the page 2 content, etc
<div id="infscr-loading"> is the loading div.
```

You could just add a bottom/top border to `.infscr-pages` so that it shows up whenever a new page is appended to the content.